# WPF get active touch points

Tags: wpf, touch

Is there a way in WPF to get active touch points? I need to determine if user is touching screen, similar to `Mouse` classes' `Pressed` -property?

I just need to know if any touch is present on the screen - don't mind what UIElement it's touching.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to your main windows ManipulationStarting event (when the first finger makes contact with the screen), ManipulationInertiaStarting event (when the last finger lifts off the screen) and/or ManipulationDelta event (when any finger moves).

Within your event handlers you can get a list of all current touchpoints via [ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.Manipulators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationdeltaeventargs.manipulators%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Don't forget to set your main window's IsManipulationEnabled to true.

This way you just have to remember whether a manipulation is currently in progress or not. You don't have to keep track of all the individual touch points yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, but they may not be the most correct way to do it:

1) You could subscribe to the `MainWindow.PreviewTouchDown` and `MainWindow.PreviewTouchUp` and maintain a list of all the current touch devices. It would be easy to implement but could make your code messy.

2) Subscribe to `Touch.FrameReported` which you can get a collection of touch points from the `TouchFrameEventArgs.GetTouchPoints(null);`. This will happen on every touch event firing, so it may be too often, but it would allow you to handle this event from any class.